# Get typescript definition files via bower?

Tags: typescript, bower

Are there any other possibilities to get TypeScript type definitions then copy from the useful [DefinitelyTyped Repo](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped%20DefinitelyTyped%20Repo) or using NuGet?
Maybe bower or something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible with bower.

First install bower by using npm:

```
npm install -g bower
```

Then install DefinitelyTyped by using bower:

```
bower install DefinitelyTyped
```

Comment: I would not reccommend this option. DefinitelyTyped in VS brings the IDE to a screaming flaming halt. Pegs my CPU near 100% even when doing nothing, with all editor windows closed for several minutes.

Comment: Note that this will get *all* TypeScript definitions available from DefinitelyTyped.

Answer (score 22):

The best option is to use `tsd`. It is like `npm` or `bower`, but for typescript definitions

```
 npm install tsd@next -g

 cd path/to/your/project
 tsd init
```

Then

```
 tsd install jQuery --save
```

That's it.

**EDIT**

There is a new TypeScript definition manager, [typings](https://github.com/typings/typings), with the goal of non-ambient type definitions used by external modules.

**EDIT**

With the future [TypeScript 2](http://www.infoworld.com/article/3052438/javascript/microsofts-typescript-20-is-due-by-june.html), you will be able to install type definitions with `npm install @types/jQuery`

Comment: @jesuslopez, you have the option to not use a package manager.

Comment: I'm currently using npm, bower and NuGet. Why we need another package manager? It just complicate things.

Comment: The original question was about how to install definitions on platforms where Nuget is not available.

Comment: You can use bower -install DefinitelyTyped

Comment: It seems like a waste of time using two JavaScript package managers.

Answer (score -1):

They can be installed via nuget e.g. https://www.nuget.org/packages/jquery.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped/

This also may be of use:

https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/tsd

Comment: As my question explains I know there is the possibility to get definitions via NuGet. I am developing on Ubuntu/Mac OS where NuGet is not the best solution.

Comment: Your question is not clear enough, it sounds like you are asking if you can install them via nuget.

Comment: Ok, a common task to get libraries and other dependencies for frontend developing is to use [bower](http://bower.io/). It would be nice to get TypeScript type definitions also via bower.