# Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type. Variable 'angular' must be of type 'IAngularStatic', but here has type 'IAngularStatic'

Tags: angularjs, typescript, definitelytyped, angular-scenario, tsd

Error happens while I try to [get definitions via tsd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28602879/get-typescript-definition-files-via-bower) from [DefinitelyTyped Repo](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped).

> Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable
>   'angular' must be of type 'IAngularStatic', but here has type
>   'IAngularStatic'

When I google this error, it gives me [this result](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/issues/1408) which redirects to [here](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/pull/1418). At that pages it seems issue solved but I can't figure out what is the solution and what should I do in my angular-scenario typedefiniton file

Environment in that thread is TS 0.9.5 + VS2013 compile error. However my environment is TS 1.5.3 +  VS2015